# Delete rows where number of zeros > positive numbers (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got an issue

My task is to filter the array
I have to turn all negative  into 0 and then return the array where all rows are filtered in accordance with these statements:

each subarray contains only positive numbers (including zeros);

each subarray has fewer zeros than the other positive numbers in it

I can't understand how to solve the second point

```
import numpy as np

def clean_out(data):
    data = np.array(data)
    data[data < 0] = 0

    r = np.sort(data, axis=0, kind='heapsort')
    return r
```

For example:

```
Test input:
-1 2 -3 -4
9 8 2 -2
6 7 -3 -5
1 7 4 3
```

I've got this result after usin' my function:

```
[[0 2 0 0]
 [1 7 0 0]
 [6 7 2 0]
 [9 8 4 3]]
```

How to delete certain rows?(in this case the first row is needed to be deleted, cuz there are 3 zeros and only one positive number)

I've tried to do this task with using
`for row in data:`
and etc. but it doesn't help me

How to delete all rows where number of zeros is more than positive numbers?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This answer assumes that the negative numbers are already converted to `0`.*

Use the numpy's [`numpy.count_nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) function, which counts the number of non-zero values in the array.

To filter *only* the rows, there is an `axis` argument for the function to do this.  The `axis` argument specifies the axis to count the positive numbers of.

Here is an example to demonstrate a usage of the function:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 2],
     [0, 0, 3],
     [2, 0, 1]]
)

np.count_nonzero(x, axis=1)  # [2, 1, 2]
```

We can then filter the original array by only selecting the number of the positives equal or larger than half of the number of columns:

```py
num_cols = x.shape[1]  # Get the number of columns
y = x[np.count_nonzero(x, axis=1) >= num_cols / 2]

print(y)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [2 0 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks homie! This solves my task.
Wish u all da best!

Answer (score 2):

The first point can be solved using `np.clip`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

txt = '''-1 2 -3 -4
9 8 2 -2
6 7 -3 -5
1 7 4 3'''

arr = np.loadtxt(StringIO(txt))

arr = np.clip(arr, 0, np.inf)
```

`arr` is:

```
[[0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [9. 8. 2. 0.]
 [6. 7. 0. 0.]
 [1. 7. 4. 3.]]
```

And the second point:

```py
s = np.sum(arr == 0, axis=1)
print(arr[s <= (len(arr) - s)])
```

Prints:

```
[[9. 8. 2. 0.]
 [6. 7. 0. 0.]
 [1. 7. 4. 3.]]
```